# DATA DIRECTORY MySQL

Tags: mysql

query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_product`
DATA DIRECTORY = '/var/lib/mysql/shop/'
INDEX DIRECTORY='/var/lib/mysql/shop/'
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

why i have this error:

**Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY**

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least two problems here.  First, your table doesn't have any columns.  Second, you can't use `DATA DIRECTORY` or `INDEX DIRECTORY` with InnoDB.

Also, beginning with MySQL 5.0.60, you cannot use path names that contain the MySQL data directory with `DATA DIRECTORY` or `INDEX DIRECTORY`.  I'm guessing that `/var/lib/mysql` is your MySQL data directory?

Comment: /var/lib/mysql yes, this my data directory

Comment: @user - then that's probably your issue.  See the mysql docs under data directory and index directory here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: As of MySQL 5.6 it's perfectly possible to use DATA DIRECTORY with InnoDB. Requirement: option `--innodb_file_per_table` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> DATA DIRECTORY works by creating symlinks from where the table would normally have been (inside the datadir) to where the option specifies. For security reasons, to avoid bypassing the privilege system, the server does not permit symlinks inside the datadir. Therefore, DATA DIRECTORY cannot be used to specify a location inside the datadir. An attempt to do so will result in an error 1210 (HY000) Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#data-directoryindex-directory

Your DATA DIRECTORY is in `/var/lib/mysql/`, try a different location, for example `/var/shop`