# MySql (Windows Server) - Create Tables in Specific folder

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a table on MySql specifing `DATA` and `INDEX DIRECTORY` commands. The problem is that my server is a Windows plataform.

When I try:

```
CREATE TABLE db.tb (tb_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY 'd:\Abc';
```

It gives me an error.

```
Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143561/data-directory-mysql

Comment: You are also missing an `=` sign while assigning Data Directory.

Comment: "\" is [esacpe chaacter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html), so try: `... DATA DIRECTORY 'd:\\Abc';`

Comment: @AxelAmthor: Information there is wrong. You can use DATA DIRECTORY with InnoDB in general - and especially with InnoDB under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement should be either

```
CREATE TABLE db.tb (
    tb_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB
DATA DIRECTORY='d:/Abc';
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE db.tb (
    tb_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB
DATA DIRECTORY='d:\\Abc';
```

because to write a backslash in a string you've got to double it and you were missing the `=` too as Syed Ali Taqi mentioned.

You should check that the innodb_file_per_table configuration option is enabled:

```
SELECT  @@innodb_file_per_table; -- should return 1
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html)

**Note:**

In the case of InnoDB `INDEX DIRECTORY` will not be needed, because the `.idb` file contains both, data and indexes, [see manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_ibd_file):

> Each InnoDB table created using the file-per-table mode goes into its
>   own tablespace file, with a .ibd extension, inside the database
>   directory. This file contains the table data and any indexes for the
>   table. File-per-table mode, controlled by the innodb_file_per_table
>   option, affects many aspects of InnoDB storage usage and performance,
>   and is enabled by default in MySQL 5.6.7 and higher.

Comment: i did worked with the "\\". Altough, the DATA DIRECTORY argument is saving it correctly i receive the "<INDEX DIRECTORY> option ignored" response. Would you know why?

Comment: It's not needed for InnoDB, because the `.idb` file contains both: data and indexes, see (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_ibd_file): *Each InnoDB table created using the file-per-table mode goes into its own tablespace file, with a .ibd extension, inside the database directory. This file contains the table data and any indexes for the table. File-per-table mode, controlled by the innodb_file_per_table option, affects many aspects of InnoDB storage usage and performance, and is enabled by default in MySQL 5.6.7 and higher.*

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: Added explanation why `INDEX DIRECTORY` is ignored.