# phpMyAdmin error #1210

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've seen several posts about MySQL error #1210 but I haven't noticed one about errors occurring within phpMyAdmin. Perhaps someone can help.

Using phpMyAdmin, I fill in the GUI form to (for example) drop an obsolete field in an existing table in an existing database. It asks me to confirm that I want to drop the field, and then fails with an error "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to DATA DIRECTORY". There's none of my coding in here, no MySQL queries of mine, just a few boxes ticked and buttons pressed, yet phpMyAdmin gives an error. I get this error with any attempt to alter a table structure.

For this particular job, the table was created with the following (which was generated by an Export from another phpMyAdmin installation)...

```
CREATE TABLE `choreovote` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `compyear` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `competition` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `memberno` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `votes` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 DATA DIRECTORY='./cloggb_db/' INDEX DIRECTORY='./cloggb_db/';
ALTER TABLE `choreovote` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `choreovote` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

And the phpMyAdmin generated query which is not working is...
    ALTER TABLE `choreovote` DROP `compyear`;

Does anyone have any idea where I should look?

Many thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL and what version of PHPMyAdmin are you currently using?

Comment: I would guess that `./cloggb_db/` is an invalid syntax. You may have to run a custom SQL  giving a correctly adjusted filepath address (such as `/usr/lib/mysql/cloggb_db/` for example

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing this on my system, and working off of some hints at [DATA DIRECTORY MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143561/data-directory-mysql), I was able to make it work after:

1. changing to a full path outside the existing MySQL data directory,
2. creating the intended directory outside of MySQL (in my case, I have shell access and just used mkdir), and
3. changing permission on the folder such that my MySQL user had permissions to access the folder and create new files.

Once I did all three of those, your SQL query ran successfully.